# Calculate mean across one specific dimension of a 4D tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, pytorch, tensor

I have a PyTorch video feature tensor of shape `[66,7,7,1024]` and I need to convert it to `[1024,66,7,7]`. How to rearrange a tensor shape? Also, how to perform mean across `dimension=1`? i.e., after performing mean of the dimension with size 66, I need the tensor to be `[1024,1,7,7]`.

I have tried to calculate the mean of dimension=1 but I failed to replace it with the mean value. And I could not imagine a 4D tensor in which one dimension is replaced by its mean.

Edit:
 I tried torch.mean(my_tensor, dim=1). But this returns me a tensor of shape [1024,7,7]. The 4D tensor is being converted to 3D. But I want it to remain 4D with shape [1024,1,7,7].

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look into `numpy.transpose`. New axes would be - `(3,0,1,2)` or `(3,0,2,1)`.

Comment: @Divakar transpose gives me (3,1,2,0). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I meant `np.transpose(a,(3,0,1,2))`, with `a` being the input array. Also, check the equivalent of `numpy.transpose` in PyTorch. Also, not sure what you meant by transpose giving you (3,1,2,0).

Comment: I could get the shape `[3,0,1,2]` from numpy to tensor using `torch.from_numpy(my_numpy_features.transpose([3,0,1,2]))`.

Comment: Use `keepdim=True` with the `mean` method.

Comment: I find there is a fantastic response in the pytorch forum already (check the final answer) and post there if you still have questions: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-different-between-dim-1-and-dim-0/61094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the question has been answered in the comments section. So we can use `tensor.transpose([3,0,1,2])` to convert the tensor to the shape `[1024,66,7,7]`.

Now mean over the temporal dimension can be taken by 
`torch.mean(my_tensor, dim=1)`
This will give a 3D tensor of shape `[1024,7,7]`.
To obtain a tensor of shape `[1024,1,7,7]`, I had to unsqueeze in dimension=1:

`tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(1)`

Comment: did you take a look at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-different-between-dim-1-and-dim-0/61094 what were your thoughts on it? Perhaps a full workable example code would help.